# if $f_n \to f$ pointwise but not uniformly on$[0,1]$ then $\lim⁡_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n (x)dx=\int_0^1\lim⁡_{n\to\infty} f_n (x)dx$

Tags: calculus

Show that the sequence $\{f_n\}$, defined by $$f_n (x)=nx(1-x)^n,$$ converges point wise but not uniformly on $[0,1]$ yet 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n (x)dx=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n (x)dx.$$

This is what I got

Proof

Assume that the sequence $\{f_n\}$, defined by $f_n (x)=nx(1-x)^n$, converges point wise but not uniformly on $[0,1]$. We will show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n (x)dx=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n (x)dx.$$

Suppose ${f_n}$ is integrable, otherwise $\int_0^1f_n (x)dx$ does not exist. Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}⁡f_n (x)=f(x),$$ we must show that $f(x)$ is also integrable, otherwise $$\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n (x)dx=\int_0^1f(x) dx$$ does not exist.

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, we obtain, there exists an $N>0$, such that for all $n\ge0$,
$|f_n-f|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$

In particular,
$$|f_N-f|=|f-f_N| <\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$$

We want to show that f is integrable, that mean, we want to show for all partition $P\in[0,1]$,
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$$

Notice that 
$$\sup ⁡\lbrace f-f_N :x\in[0,1]\rbrace\le \frac{\varepsilon}{4}<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$

And

$$\inf ⁡\{f-f_N :x\in[0,1]\}\ge-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}>-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$

Since ${f_n}$ is integrable, for all partition $P\in[0,1]$,

$$U(f_N,P)-L(f_N,P)<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$

Note that 
$$U(f-f_N,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n|M_i  \Delta x_i|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3} \sum_{i=1}^n\Delta x_i =\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$

Similarly , we obtain $L(f-f_N,P)<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$.

Observe that

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=U(f-f_N+f_N,P)-L(f-f_N+f_N,P)\le U(f-f_N,P)-L(f-f_N,P)+U(f_N,P)-L(f_N,P)\\
 <|U(f-f_N,P)|-|L(f-f_N,P)|+U(f_N,P)-L(f_N,P)<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon$$

This show that $f$ is integrable. Now I'm stuck

Comment: To evaluate the required integrals, just set $u=1-x$. Also note the pointwise limit is the zero function.

Comment: You *can't* assume the pointwise convergence, *do* the easy calculations. It will be zero for all $x$, so integrable. And each function is integrable because is continuous.

Comment: are you saying that I don't need to prove $f$ is integral? can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Yes. Just prove the pointwise limit is indeed the zero function. The zero function is integrable, as are all the $(f_n)$ (they're all continuous). So just evaluate the integrals. The substitution I suggested above will make this task easy.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif, I've edited your post to better use $\LaTeX$. Please note that you don't need to use Unicode characters to typeset Greek letters or sums/integrals and other frequently used math symbols. Also, to make a displayed equation, you can use double dollar signs. You can see how it's done if you click on "edited X mins ago" link under your answer and check out the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple to see that the pointwise limit of $(f_n)_n$ is the zero function but
$$||f_n||_\infty\ge f_n\left(\frac 1 n\right)=\left(1-\frac 1 n\right)^n\to e^{-1}\ne0$$
so the convergence isn't uniform on the interval $[0,1]$.

Moreover we have by integration by parts
$$\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1nx(1-x)^ndx=\frac n{n+1}\int_0^1(1-x)^{n+1}dx=-\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}(1-x)^{n+2}\Big|_0^1=\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}\to0=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)dx$$

Notice that the uniform convergence is a **sufficient condition** to interchange the limit with the integral sign but it isn't **necessary condition**.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does this $||fn||_∞$ mean?

Comment: $||f_n||_\infty=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)|$ and we know that $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent to the zero function iff
$$||f_n||_\infty\to0$$